# Appcelerator - C2dm on Android

Tags: android, titanium, push-notification, appcelerator, android-c2dm

I've been trying to install the C2dm module for titanium studio found here: https://github.com/Kuraturpa/titanium-c2dm

I keep having issues. When I set it up as outlined here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/38451/c2dm-in-titanium

I keep getting an error that it can't find the module (at runtime). The error reads:

> Location: [357, 0] /tmp/module.js Message: Error: Requested module not
>   found: com.findlaw.titanium.cd2m (/tmp/module.js#357)

I indeed can't find this file anywhere in my stuff, because I don't have a tmp folder in my project. I originally put the xml code from that above forum post in the timodule.xml file and it got me to this runtime error. When I switch it to the tiapp.xml file I get this error:

> [ERROR] The 'apiversion' for 'com.findlaw.titanium.c2dm' in the module
>   manifest is not a valid value. Please use a version of the module that
>   has an 'apiversion' value of 2 or greater set in it's manifest file

When I try to manually build the module myself using ant, I get:

> BUILD FAILED /Users/sammy/Downloads/IGx89-titanium-c2dm-3b05b8a
>   2/build.xml:9: Cannot find /Library/Application
>   Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/module/android/build.xml
>   imported from /Users/sammy/Downloads/IGx89-titanium-c2dm-3b05b8a
>   2/build.xml

I checked, and the build.xml file is in the folder shown in the error. I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do here...

Answer (score 0):

That module does not support the version of Titanium Mobile you are using (1.8.0.1 or higher). You must either update it yourself, or find another C2DM module.

The guide for porting to 1.8.0.1 is available here:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Android_Module_Porting_Guide_for_1.8.0.1